# There is a dotted line around the bubble of my carousel in Mozilla. how to remove It?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bubble dotted line image:

[image]

The dotted lines are working fine in Chrome. but In Mozilla Firefox the dotted line are taking for all the bubble along. The dotted lines should take Individual bubble. Attached the image for reference

Comment: We need your html and css...Wild guess: Add 'outline:none', somewhere in your css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your CSS the following code:

```
outline: none;
```

I believe you will have somewhere in your CSS a class call something like "carousel button" or something of that sort, well that's where it should go.

It would help to have a copy of your CSS so I could tell you exactly where to put it.

Comment: outline:none; completely remove the dotted boarder, but I want the border to be appear to be individual bubble. In attached image you can see that dotted line is not for individual. It is appearing only in mozill.

Comment: For that I would need a copy of your code. You would most likely need to put the outline code somewhere else or could create a similar effect by adding a dotted border to each buttons with this CSS: border: 1px dotted black;